# Legal characters for SASS and SCSS variable names

Tags: css, sass

What characters are valid for use in SCSS variable names?

Comment: @Chandrakant The question is very clear as it stands; there's no room for elaboration.

Comment: @meagar: The quality filter would seem to [disagree](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17191265/revisions) :P

Comment: @BoltClock but do you disagree?

Comment: @BoltClock The quality filter was wrong, I think you know it's hardly infallible. I'm sure it would have been just fine with "I'm kind of a noob to SASS and this is my first question, and I've been looking all over, but I can't really find an answer, so if you guys could help me out I'd really appreciate it, so what I'm trying to find out is, when I have a variable in SASS, like a thing with `$variable`, what are the kinds of characters I can use in the name of the variable that I am typing, like what are the valid letters I can use after the `$`? Thanks in advance, lots of love, --accipheran"

Comment: @meagar: I was being facetious - I was hoping the use of an emoticon would help convey that, but I guess not.

Comment: @boltclock, haha, guess that slipped by both of us

Comment: @cimmanon I searched google and finding an answer wasn't as easy as I thought it should have been, so I made an SO post about it. I actually *think* I know the answer to the question, but I'm not positive. I'm posting this here more for the community than for myself, so that the next person who wants to find this out has a nice SO post to go to. It's not stopping me from getting anything done.

Comment: @cimmanon The quality of your comments are really woeful. Everywhere I go I see you telling people they are lazy or their questions are poor. This is a Q&A site. Sometimes people ask questions because they are interested in seeing other people's answers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you check out the source for the [SASS lexer](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/stable/lib/sass/script/lexer.rb), you'll see:

```
# A hash of regular expressions that are used for tokenizing.
REGULAR_EXPRESSIONS = {
  :whitespace => /\s+/,
  :comment => COMMENT,
  :single_line_comment => SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT,
  :variable => /(\$)(#{IDENT})/,
  :ident => /(#{IDENT})(\()?/,
  :number => /(-)?(?:(\d*\.\d+)|(\d+))([a-zA-Z%]+)?/,
  :color => HEXCOLOR,
  :bool => /(true|false)\b/,
  :null => /null\b/,
  :ident_op => %r{(#{Regexp.union(*IDENT_OP_NAMES.map{|s| Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(s) + "(?!#{NMCHAR}|\Z)")})})},
  :op => %r{(#{Regexp.union(*OP_NAMES)})},
}
```

Which references the `IDENT` character set defined in a [separate file](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/e7bd7963e78ca84b216d8e059347d599d178a67f/lib/sass/scss/rx.rb):

```
s = if Sass::Util.ruby1_8?
      '\200-\377'
    elsif Sass::Util.macruby?
      '\u0080-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\U00010000-\U0010FFFF'
    else
      '\u{80}-\u{D7FF}\u{E000}-\u{FFFD}\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}'
    end

H = /[0-9a-fA-F]/
UNICODE = /\\#{H}{1,6}[ \t\r\n\f]?/

NONASCII = /[#{s}]/
ESCAPE = /#{UNICODE}|\\[ -~#{s}]/
NMSTART = /[_a-zA-Z]|#{NONASCII}|#{ESCAPE}/
NMCHAR = /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]|#{NONASCII}|#{ESCAPE}/

IDENT = /-?#{NMSTART}#{NMCHAR}*/
```

So, it looks like variable names can contain:

- Any ASCII letter.
- Any number 0-9 (as long as it is not the first character in the name).
- Underscores and hyphens.
- ASCII punctuation (`!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^{|}~`) and spaces, if escaped with a backslash.
- Unicode characters in the ranges `0080-D7FF`, `E000-FFFD`, or `10000-10FFFF`.
- Unicode hex escape sequences such as `\00E4`.

Comment: For the record,having tried +, < and >, I can confirm that they do NOT work in variable names, at least with my sass compiler (3.2.12).

Comment: @lytnus that's correct; as noted in the answer, ASCII punctuation must be escaped with a backslash if used in a variable name (e.g. `$foo\+bar\<baz` works, but not `$foo+bar<baz`). I'm not sure why this would ever be useful, but the grammar allows for it.

Comment: By the way, for everyone's convenience, a regex that matches the ASCII punctuation that must be replaced is the following: /["!#$%&\'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^\{\}|~]/g