# How to target all scss variables which is used for styling with regex

Tags: regex, sass, scss-mixins

Hi i want to target all the scss variables which is used for styles

**Question:** i want to target all the scss variables which comes after : with $name it might come inside ($name) as shown in below image (**red color highlight**)

**My Expectation is shown in below image(red color highlight):**

[image]

From above image i want to highlight all the red color marked variables

here is what i have tried

```
(:)(\s+\$+.*;)
```

Which fails so many test cases

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/WtyoF6/1

**Request:** please include any other testcases if you know.

Please help me thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Positive lookbehind: `/(?<=\:\s*)(\$+.*;)/gm`

Comment: @Pieterjan ,it is working for some more test cases then the asked question but fails for `$primary-color: darken($primary-color, 60%);` and some others

Comment: What it the tool or language and what are the examples of "some others"?

Comment: @Thefourthbird it is not working with all the testcases i,e what i meant by some other you can see here https://regex101.com/r/tGz2P0/1

Comment: @EaBengaluru Perhaps something like this? `(?<=:[^$\n]*)\$[^$;\n]*;` https://regex101.com/r/ONUihs/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird sorry for late reply, now highlight is happening for all test cases but it should highlight only $variables  as shown in image  https://ibb.co/SV53qWY

Comment: @EaBengaluru your image link is broken

Comment: @AaronMeese sorry for that here is the updated link  https://ibb.co/Bq3S5tb

Comment: Please add a language tag, this is only for Javascript? Thought of [e.g. this (pcre demo)](https://regex101.com/r/ISkyY5/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194994/) as a reference for the valid SASS/SCSS variable characters the following regex should match all* valid SASS/SCSS variables:

```
(\$(?![0-9])(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_\u0080-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]|(?:\\[!"#$%&'\(\)*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^{|}~]))+)
```

**Explaination**

- `(` capturing group around the whole SASS variable name

  - `\$` starts with a `$`
  - `(?![0-9])` negative lookahead - the first character cannot be a number
  - `(?:` non-capturing group of the valid characters

    - `[a-zA-Z0-9-_\u0080-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]` any letter, number, dash, underscore, or characters with the ranges `0080` to `D7FF`, `E000` to `FFFD` (the range `10000` to `10FFFF` is missing because the regex engine won't accept it as a valid range)
    - `|` or
    - `(?:` non-capturing group of special characters that are escaped buy a `\`

      - `\\` back-slash
      - `[!"#$%&'\(\)*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^{|}~]` any of these special characters
    - `)`
  - `)+` one or more of the valid characters
- `)`

* Any characters in the range `10000` to `10FFFF` won't match as the regex engine won't accept this as a valid range.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DayYBV/3)

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool or language listed, but for the example data, if a quantifier in a lookbehind assertion is supported:

```
(?<=:[^:$\n]*)\$\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `:[^:$\n]*` Match `:` followed by optionally repeating any char except `:` `$` or a newline
- `)` Close the lookbehind assertion
- `\$\w+(?:-\w+)*` Match `$` 1+ word chars and optionally repeat matching `-` and 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7a2UNT/1)

Or else with a capture group:

```
(?::[^:$\n]*)(\$\w+(?:-\w+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mAVSHJ/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for all occurrences of SCSS variables that are being used, this will work for you:

```
:.*(\$[a-zA-Z-]+)
```

A demo can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/WtyoF6/4).

Comment: it solves almost 90% of the problem  https://regex101.com/r/w4SY89/1

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, it would be helpful if you updated your question with everything you want highlighted

Comment: it must match all variables according to this https://ibb.co/Bq3S5tb . even edited the question

Comment: i have edited my question and even opened bounty of 50 please have a look

Comment: My answer highlights exactly what you ask for, I'm not sure what else you want. Every single capture group is identical to your picture

Comment: variable can't be start with number `$3color`

Answer (score 1):

This regex will exactly find all the red highlighted values in your example (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6ae37/1)):

```
(?<=:[^$\n]*)(\$[^\s:;,]*)
```

Or if you prefer to avoid the positive lookbehind, use the first capturing group from here (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZY4pB8/1)):

```
(?::[^$\n]*)(\$[^\s:;,]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(:)(.+)(\$.+((,)))|(:)(.+)(\$.+((\s)))|(:)(.+)(\$.+(([;])))`

In my hack above, I match everything that comes after `:` until space`\s`, comma`,`, or semicolon`;` and then differentiate the appropriate $name in the `$3` of `$1$2$3$4`.

So, if you need to replace the $name you will use `$1$2$3$4` and change the `$3` to what you need to replace it with.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8QoxLF/1)